# Checking for component links/RTF component links when creating component core service

Tags: core-service

I was wondering if there's a way before creating a component to check for component links either from the fields of the component or through RTF.

I'm using the following code that is creating a copy of existing components. The aim is to take components from one publication and copy them to another programmatically. Whilst doing this I need to check the contents of every component for component links and recreate them too

The code below isn't complete yet as I still need to change the location of the component to be that of the target publication but you will get the jist of where the component fields are coming from.

```
public string Create(CoreServiceClient client, string componentId)
{
var compData = (ComponentData)client.Read(componentId, new ReadOptions());

var component = (ComponentData)client.GetDefaultData(ItemType.Component, compData.LocationInfo.OrganizationalItem.IdRef);

component.Id = "tcm:0-0-0";
component.Title = compData.Title;
component.Content = compData.Content;
component.Schema.IdRef = compData.Schema.IdRef;

try
{
    component = (ComponentData)client.Create(component, new ReadOptions());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to create component: " + ex);
}

return component.Id;
}
```

Is there a way I can target individual fields and get out tcm ids of component links?

The component links could come from either a RTF or individual fields in the component. So I guess I'd need to target the component.Component field and check for tcm ids here?

Many thanks

Comment: Your question is a bit misleading. You're asking about retrieving component links from existing components, yet showing a code sample for creating new components.  Where will the values come from for the new components?

Comment: I am a little confused by your code. It looks like it is creating a copy of an existing component in the same folder. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. I've edited my question to explain the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Component links are typically anchor tags with a tcm id or have a "tridion" prefix on the href attribute, e.g. `<a tridion:href="tcm:a:b">blah</a>`.  You can extract this from the entire component xml by running it through a regular expression.  Here is a sample (I'm sure the regex can be optimized, alas, it works):

```
Regex TridionHrefExpression = new Regex(@"(?<tagname><(?<a>[^\s>]+)[^>]+tridion:href[^>]+?>)|(?<option><option.+tridion:value[^>]+>)", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Compiled);

foreach (Match matchingElement in TemplateUtilities.GetRegexMatches(outputContainer, TridionHrefExpression))
{
    linkTag = matchingElement.Groups[0].Value;

    //.. do stuff
}
```

Comment: You might also consider just using an XPath expression to iterate through those nodes as the content is stored as XML //@xlink:href[contains(., 'tcm:')] should give you all the href attributes containing TCMURIs inb the Component XML

Comment: Chris is right. Why on earth would you use a regex to find an XML Attribute?? In fact, I think you can also say that the xlink:href attributes will all be tcm uris.